# Javascript/jQuery back to top script

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to create "Back to top" button which takes the user to the top of the page, but I need it to fade in and fade out. 
When the user is at the top, obviously it should not appear and when the user scrolls down a little it should fade in, then fade out when its back at the top threshold. 
I Have attempted to some work on here, here is some code:

```
<a href="#top"><img src="images/top.png" class="totop" /></a>

<div id="top"></div>
.totop{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
    z-index:11;
    position:fixed;
}
```

It is actually absolute to the most outer layer, so it will stick in position of the browser. which is fine. However im not sure how to make it fade in/out as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but here's a quick hacked together solution. There is room for improvement, but you should get the general idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/captray/69BNP/1/

```
var whereYouWantYourButtonToAppear = 200;

$(window).scroll(function(){

    var position = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(position > whereYouWantYourButtonToAppear)
    {
        $('#backToTop').fadeIn();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#backToTop').fadeOut();
    }
});

$('#backToTop').on('click', function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the scrolltop method in jquery.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/ChDdE/

eg

```
$("button").click(function(){
   alert($("div").scrollTop());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 10 && !$('#top').is(":visible") ) { //if user scrolled 10px from the top and element is not visible
            $('#top').fadeIn(300);
        } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 10 && $('#top').is(":visible")) {
            $('#top').fadeOut(300);
        }
    });
});
```

I recommend to use position fixed on the element to make it relative to the browserwindow.

Comment: this only fades in, it doesnt fadeout when i scroll back to the top

Comment: I misspelled fadeOut. It need an uppercase O. After adding this it will work. @user3495256. Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/48sSS/